# Check message signature in solidity

Tags: solidity

Is there a way to do basic decryption in Solidity?

For example:

Given 3 actors and message:

1. Server
2. Client
3. Solidity contract

The flow:

1. Server generates message and signs with `private key`
2. Client uses the message as parameter to call contract
3. Contract uses server's `public key` to decrypt the message (make sure it came from server)

Is there a way in Solidity to do "decrypt" a string using a pubkey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your looking for signature verification, not decryption.

Yes, notably, Solidity includes a function [`ecrecover`](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/units-and-global-variables.html#mathematical-and-cryptographic-functions) that can recover the account that signed a message.

For details about how to use this to sign and verify messages, see https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/02/17/signing-and-verifying-messages-in-ethereum/.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a signature and the message that was signed, you can get the address that signed the message using the `ecrecover` function in Solidity.

It is explained in [this tutorial](https://www.0xdev.co/how-to-verify-a-signature-in-a-smart-contract-in-solidity/).

You need to split the signature into 3 parts like this:

```
const signature = "0x...."

const r = signature.slice(0, 66);
const s = "0x" + signature.slice(66, 130);
const v = parseInt(signature.slice(130, 132), 16);
```

And then in Solidity you can verify the signature like this:

```
function verify(bytes32 _data, uint8 _v, bytes32 _r, bytes32 _s) public pure returns (address) {
    bytes memory prefix = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32";
    bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(prefix, _data));
    address signer = ecrecover(hash, _v, _r, _s);
    return signer;
}
```